# When calculating cyclomatic complexity, should statements exiting the current method/function be part of it?

Tags: java, c, metrics, cyclomatic-complexity

This probably applies to more than C and Java, of course, but those are the two languages I am more familiar with, so let us take this simple example:

```
int foo(int arg)
{
    if (arg > 0)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Now, I have seen two interpretations as far as `return` is concerned:

- this is a "different code path" since it exits the method; as such any `return` statement should increase the complexity by 1. In this case, the sample code above has a complexity of 3; or
- `return` just exits the method, no reason to count it in. In this case, the sample code above has a complexity of 1.

Is any interpretation above the "correct", canonical one as far as cyclomatic complexity is concerned? I tend to favor the latter case but I'm no CS theorist...

Comment: C does not have _methods_. And that is a _function_ anyway.

Comment: @Olaf that is irrelevant to the discussion at hand. A method or a function is nothing more than a code path

Comment: A method is related to an object, _function_ is the more overall term. There are good reason to call a dog not "wolf".

Comment: @Olaf dogs, wolves, werewolves, whatever; coupling is not complexity!

Answer (score 3):

That code has two distinct paths through the function:  one that corresponds to `arg > 0` being true and the other corresponding to it being false.

The number of return statements involved does not affect that, since it does not change the number of distinct paths through the function.   Your code could be rewritten as

```
int foo(int arg)
{
     int retval = 0;
     if (arg > 0) retval = 1;
     return retval;
}
```

which has exactly the same number of paths, despite having one less return statement.

Comment: Not to mention that you could also have written that code with the `?:` ternary operator.. Hmm

Comment: The ternary operator has two distinct paths through it,so changes nothing in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Your cyclomatic complexity would be 2, here's why:

Your code is essentially this:

```
int foo(int arg)
    {
        int out;
        if (arg > 0)
            out = 1;
        else
            out = 0;
        return out;
    }
```

plain `return` statement dont count toward complexity. You only have 1 `if` statement, no `if else` statements. Hence, your cyclomatic complexity will be 2, as there is 1 alternate path to the main path.
If return statements would count, your cyclomatic complexity of the same method could be 3 OR 4 (see my code vs yours), this should make clear why return statements aren't included.

Comment: I believe the cyclomatic complexity of OP's code is 2, as there are clearly 2 linearly independent paths through the code.

Comment: @d125q but then there is always a path in the code, right? Does it really count in complexity calculations? Would that mean that only functions/methods _with no statements_ would have a complexity of 0?

Comment: You are correct, as there is always at least 1 path, adding an if statement will make the complexity 2: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity

Comment: @fge: Going by the definition of cyclomatic complexity and control flow graphs, the cyclomatic complexity of an empty function is 1.

Comment: @d125q makes sense... I need to re-read everything from the start again, I believe